# Can't execute any database commands in Rails. mysql and mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I see this error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
/Users/jwan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
```

and I don't know what's going on:

This is my versions for Rails, mysql and mysql2:

```
mysql2 (~> 0.3.0)

rails (= 4.1.5)
```

and

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Any ideas as to what's going on? I downgraded my mysql version via:

```
brew unlink mysql
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link mysql@5.7 --force
```

Comment: Does mysqld actually run? What is output of `ps ax | grep mysql | grep -v grep`?

Comment: Ah I need to just start it. Is there anyway to run it without sudo?

Comment: If the problem persists after starting mysql server, please share your ```database.yml```

Answer (score 1):

Use `brew services start mysql@5.7` to start the daemon and configure it to run at startup.